# do not embed custom font into Prawn generated PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf, fonts, prawn

I use Prawn to generate PDF.
When I use custom font (Arial CE with central/east european characters), the font is embedded into target PDF.

```
pdf.font_families.update(
        "Arial" => {
                :bold        => "font/arialbd.ttf",
                :italic      => "font/ariali.ttf",
                :bold_italic => "font/arialbi.ttf",
                :normal      => "font/arial.ttf"
        }
)
pdf.font "Arial"
pdf.text "Účet", :size => 18
```

Problem is the size of PDF. Embedded font increases document size from 4kB to 80kB and I don't need to put font into every PDF because Arial CE is available on client machines.

Any suggestions how to use custom font without embedding it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately prawn has no way to turn off embedding of custom fonts.

You can use the build in fonts like Arial and Times New Roman, and they wont be embedded, but then you're not getting the look you're after.

Comment: It seems that I need to patch prawn to replace provided fonts with external Arial. Or I have to add flag for non-embedding fonts into target PDF somehow.

Comment: Would the built-in Arial be enough if it supported eastern european characters? if so, patching prawn to do that might be the easier option and will be useful to many other prawn users. I can offer guidance on the required changes.

Comment: There is no Arial in https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/tree/master/data/fonts directory. I can try to add Arial to my prawn, add it to https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/font.rb and test it.

Problem is that Arial is not free font so it can't be distributed with prawn.

Better solution will be adding "no-include" parameter to the font selection method and to pdf generation method too.

Comment: Another option would be to "stroke and fill" the text as a shape, instead of rendering it as text. Does anyone know how to do that with Prawn?